# Linq errors on cast. Possible to keep successful conversions?

Tags: .net, linq, csv

Anyone know how to (or if its possible) when using linq if one of the iterations fails to just ignore the fails and keep the successful. Example: when I'm importing a CSV:

```
string[] csvRows = File.ReadAllLines(fiList[fileCount].FullName);      

var Rows = from row in csvRows.Skip(1)
           let data = row.Split(',')
           select new
           {
               Reference = data[0],
               RequestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data[1]),
           };
```

and the csv looks like:

> Reference, RequestDate ref1,20/06/10
>   00:00:00 ref2,55/06/10 00:00:00

Obviously, it'll fail on the second one as it can't convert to a datetime ("String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."). Is there any way to force .net to ignore this and just return the first row?

Cheers in advance

Stu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could test and filter out the invalid rows:

```
var rows = csvRows.Skip(1).Select(r => 
    {
        var data = r.Split(',');
        DateTime result;

        if(DateTime.TryParse(data[1], out result))
            return new { Reference = data[0], RequestDate = result};
        else return null;
    }).Where( x=> x!=null);
```

Personally I'd go for a `foreach` loop in this case which would make the code more readable.

An alternative to support readability is to factor out the validity testing (just an example):

```
public static bool IsValidColumnSet(string[] data)
{
    DateTime result;

    if(DateTime.TryParse(data[1], out result))
        return true;
    else return false;
}

var Rows = from row in csvRows.Skip(1)
           let data = row.Split(',')
           where IsValidColumnSet(data)
           select new
           {
               Reference = data[0],
               RequestDate = Convert.ToDateTime(data[1]),
           };
```

Comment: Great answer. This seems like it would work although my code above is a bit stripped down, I need to check for several dates but I guess I could just go if(DateTime.TryParse(data[1], out result) && DateTime.TryParse(data[5], out result)) etc..?

Comment: @stuartw87: you can just write "normal" code inside the lambda expression as long as you return an instance of the type you want to work with further along - so yes you could do that.

Comment: Thanks again BrokenGlass. I've got this working now and helps with my other requirement to strip out and store those bad rows.

Comment: @stuartw87: Check my update, I would factor out the validity check in a separate method.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just recoding my class now .. passing off to a separate method seems to be the way to go. I prefer more readable code! Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can add `where DateTime.TryParse(data[1], out yourvar);` to your linq clause.  Didn't test it but it should work.